Is there a word/phrase that describes things people say to be "the smartest person in the room"?
Examples would be
(1) The tomato is not a vegetable
(2) Washington didn't really cut the Cherry Tree
(3) no evidence that Marie Antoinette said "let them eat cake"

This is more a single-word request and so requires a sample sentence. (I added the tag before realizing the defect and deciding to undo the addition for now.) As to the popular-refrains tag, I'm not sure what to make of it: clicking on the tag brings up a number of questions that seem to fit it as ill as the present.

Parson Weems's cherry-tree yarn concerns Washington, not Lincoln.

your entire comment is an example that I am looking for a name for  @briandonovan

A word for the things they say? Or a word for them?

The three examples don't seem to be intended to display the smartness of the person; at best, if successful, they would show that the person is well informed, which is a quality different from smartness.

For me, these are examples of factoids that many of us know and don't appreciate being reminded of, especially if the same person is heard saying all three things at the same party.

What's the connection between those three statements and smartness?

Also, many others, including What is the word ... synonymous to arrogant or ostensibly knowledgable? & verb meaning 'to act pedantic'.

See also term meaning careful and thorough – almost excessively so, where answers overlap.

Pedantry is an excessive focus on the correctness of minor details. Eschewing the common, colloquial, and culinary classification of a tomato as a vegetable and insisting that must be treated as a botanical fruit is a good example of this excessive attention to formalism. Often a pedant is perceived unfavorably by others as boasting about their own knowledge, since no one else really cares about whatever minor detail they are correcting.

Wise men say "Tomatoes Are Berries and Strawberries Are Not" @nuclearhoagie

I appreciate the autological nature of your answer.

Tomatoes, cucumbers, eggplants - things that are botanically fruits but culinarily vegetables - are what my sister calls "salad fruits". :)

For the people who say such things, I suggest smart aleck, know-it-all, or showoff (n.) / show off (v.), although showoff isn't limited to intelligence. Other put-downs include wiseass, wiseacre,and  smarty-pants.
To describe the behavior demonstrated by those saying these kinds of things, you could say that the wiseacres are showing off by nitpicking with irrelevant factoids.
smart aleck (n.)

An obnoxiously conceited and self-assertive person with pretensions to
smartness or cleverness
M-W

know-it-all (n.)

Informal + disapproving A person who talks and behaves like someone who knows everything
My neighbor is a real know-it-all, always telling
me what to do.
M-W

showoff (n.)

A person given to making a show of or drawing public attention to his
or her possessions, accomplishments, skill, etc.; a person who behaves
in an ostentatious or attention-seeking manner.
[OED online]

wiseacre (n.)

One who pretends to knowledge or cleverness
especially : smart aleck
M-W

The embarrassment of choices tells us no one likes a know-it-all. That said, what better time to point out that the U.S. Supreme Court ruled that the tomato is classified as a vegetable; V8 Juice (literally) counts on this.


"Oh, no you can't Mr. Know-It-all," said the pig. "The only thing you
are better at...is bragging and giving orders!
Billie Atamer; Leo
the Know It All Rooster (2021)


When you really want to show off  your intelligence, it's time to
whip out the philosophy conversation. Luckily, there might be about
twelve people who have actually studied philosophy (and most of them
are manning the drive-thru at the local Burger Barn), so you'll rarely
find yourself having to go brain to brain with a philosophy expert.
David Matalon and Chris Woolsey; The Concise Guide to Sounding Smart
at Parties  (2006)


nitpicking (n.)

Minute and usually unjustified criticism
M-W

factoid (n.)

A briefly stated and usually trivial fact
M-W

